# Comparing NSDates to determine day or night?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm parsing a weather XML that gives me the sunrise + sunset times for the user's location.  I've parsed them as strings, and they look like this: `7:20 am` and `5:34 pm`, for example.

I then converted these two times into an `NSDate` by doing this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *Sunrise = [dateFormat dateFromString:sunrise]; 
NSDate *Sunset = [dateFormat dateFromString:sunset];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];      
[dateFormat release];
```

Now I have three dates which I now want to compare to determine whether the current time is night or day.  The problem is, when I `NSLog` the Sunrise and Sunset times I see that the year is **1970** on both the dates that came from strings.  I don't know where to start on how to compare the dates.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres actually a pretty simple way to do this. NSDateFormatter has a method called `setDefaultDate:` which basically uses a given date object to fill in any fields not included by the date format string. So, using the variables from your sample:

```
[dateFormat setDefaultDate:today];
```

Just put this line before the calls to `dateFromString:`, and you should be good to go.

Reference: [NSDateFormatter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setDateFormat%3a)

Comment: That's great, I'll use that in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow this is new to me and I think I'll have to refactor some code now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may split up a NSDate into Date Components, you'll need a NSCalendar Object and tell it to give you a NSDateComponents Instance for your date.

Like so:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Parts: Day %d, Month %d, Year %d", [comps day], [comps month], [comps year]);
```

Instead of the example "unitFlags" you may OR together any of the NS*CalenderUnit Flags to get the corresponding elements into "comps". In your case it would be something like NSHourCalenderUnit | NSMinuteCalenderUnit .

Comment: Might be a little complicated for my needs, but thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your sunrise and sunset NSString variables to contain the current date.  Something like "2010-12-15 7:20am".  Once you parse that, your Sunrise and Sunset dates will be correct, and the comparison should be easy.

Comment: As this will be dynamic; I can't alter the dates in the XML file.

Comment: You can control the string being passed into dateFromString however. It might be as simple as appending "today" as in "7.20pm today" into your function. dateFromString is fairly clever.